# Combine and count same date or duplicate in json

Tags: angularjs, json, date, duplicates

I want to combine and count the date. All date are in UTC Time Zone, I first convert all UTC time to local time using toLocaleDateString() then make that date as a key to JSON object, but not get the result as expected.

My JSON Format:

```
[{"UploadTimeStamp":"2017-02-18T09:01:43.060Z"},
{"UploadTimeStamp":"2017-02-19T04:09:43.347Z"},
{"UploadTimeStamp":"2017-02-21T14:38:40.157Z"},
{"UploadTimeStamp":"2017-02-22T11:30:58.546Z"},
{"UploadTimeStamp":"2017-02-22T11:31:35.514Z"},
{"DoneTimeStamp":"2017-02-19T03:54:34.791Z"},
{"DoneTimeStamp":"2017-02-19T17:48:40.041Z"},
{"DoneTimeStamp":"2017-02-21T14:55:33.335Z"},
{"DoneTimeStamp":"2017-02-17T15:01:32.426Z"}]
```

Result:

```
{"18/02/2017":{"Upload":1},
"19/02/2017":{"Upload":1},
"21/02/2017":{"Upload":1},
"22/02/2017":{"Upload":"[object Object]1","Done":"[object Object]1"},
"17/02/2017":{"Done":1}}
```

My code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

                if (result[i].UploadTimeStamp) {

                    var value = new Date(result[i].UploadTimeStamp).toLocaleDateString();
                    //increment counter for this value (starting at 1)
                    var count = (temp[value] || 0) + 1;

                    if (temp[value] === undefined) {

                        temp[value] = {}
                        temp[value].Upload = count;

                    }
                    else {

                        temp[value].Upload = count;

                    }
                }
                else {

                    var value = new Date(result[i].DoneTimeStamp).toLocaleDateString();
                    //increment counter for this value (starting at 1)
                    var count = (temp[value] || 0) + 1;

                    if (temp[value] === undefined) {

                        temp[value] = {}
                        temp[value].Done = count;

                    }
                    else {

                        temp[value].Done = count;

                    }      
                }

            }

            console.log(JSON.stringify(temp))
```

My Expected Result

```
{"18/02/2017":{"Upload":1,"Done":0},
"19/02/2017":{"Upload":1,"Done":2},
"21/02/2017":{"Upload":1,"Done":1},
"22/02/2017":{"Upload":1,"Done":1},
"17/02/2017":{"Done":1,"Upload":0}}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var data = [{"UploadTimeStamp":"2017-02-18T09:01:43.060Z"},
{"UploadTimeStamp":"2017-02-19T04:09:43.347Z"},
{"UploadTimeStamp":"2017-02-21T14:38:40.157Z"},
{"UploadTimeStamp":"2017-02-22T11:30:58.546Z"},
{"UploadTimeStamp":"2017-02-22T11:31:35.514Z"},
{"DoneTimeStamp":"2017-02-19T03:54:34.791Z"},
{"DoneTimeStamp":"2017-02-19T17:48:40.041Z"},
{"DoneTimeStamp":"2017-02-21T14:55:33.335Z"},
{"DoneTimeStamp":"2017-02-17T15:01:32.426Z"}];
var tmp = {};

data.forEach(function(d){
    let key = Object.keys(d)[0];    
    let value = new Date(d[key]).toLocaleDateString();
    key === "UploadTimeStamp" ? key = "upload": key = "done";
    tmp[value] = tmp[value] || {};
    tmp[value].upload = tmp[value].upload || 0;
    tmp[value].done = tmp[value].done || 0;
    tmp[value][key] += 1;
});

console.log(tmp);
```

Comment: Your code is working thank you so much, i want to add done = 0 if not found doneTimeStamp on particular date and vise verse 22/02/2017": {
    "upload": 2, "done":0},"17/02/2017":{"done":1,"upload":0}

Comment: added tmp[value].done = tmp[value].done || 0; in "IF BLOCK" and tmp[value].upload = tmp[value].upload || 0; in ELSE Block is it correct? Solved my problem

Comment: Great and its working but the last issue is date are not in order any solution or suggestion?

Comment: @Beginner You have an object. You cannot order things inside an object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136473/discussion-between-beginner-and-weedoze).

Answer (score 2):

You weren't checking if .Done or .Upload is undefined, but whole object for that date. Check lines where you set var count.

```
var result = [{"UploadTimeStamp":"2017-02-18T09:01:43.060Z"},
{"UploadTimeStamp":"2017-02-19T04:09:43.347Z"},
{"UploadTimeStamp":"2017-02-21T14:38:40.157Z"},
{"UploadTimeStamp":"2017-02-22T11:30:58.546Z"},
{"UploadTimeStamp":"2017-02-22T11:31:35.514Z"},
{"DoneTimeStamp":"2017-02-19T03:54:34.791Z"},
{"DoneTimeStamp":"2017-02-19T17:48:40.041Z"},
{"DoneTimeStamp":"2017-02-21T14:55:33.335Z"},
{"DoneTimeStamp":"2017-02-17T15:01:32.426Z"}];

var temp = {}
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

                if (result[i].UploadTimeStamp) {
                    var value = new Date(result[i].UploadTimeStamp).toLocaleDateString();
                    //increment counter for this value (starting at 1)
                    var count = ((temp[value] && temp[value].Upload)? temp[value].Upload: 0) + 1;

                    if (temp[value] === undefined) {

                        temp[value] = {}
                        temp[value].Upload = count;

                    }
                    else {

                        temp[value].Upload = count;

                    }
                }
                else {

                    var value = new Date(result[i].DoneTimeStamp).toLocaleDateString();
                    //increment counter for this value (starting at 1)
                    var count = ((temp[value] && temp[value].Done)? temp[value].Done: 0) + 1;

                    if (temp[value] === undefined) {

                        temp[value] = {}
                        temp[value].Done = count;

                    }
                    else {

                        temp[value].Done = count;

                    }      
                }

            }

            console.log(JSON.stringify(temp))
```

Comment: Thank You @tomek550